# I cannot connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I cannot connect to MySQL database. It happened after updating MySQL and JDK. I added `useSSL=false`, but no result. This is the exception I get from eclipse:

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

```
package card;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Database {
    private staticConnection con = null;

    public Database()
    {

    }

    public static Connection connect() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        return con=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gym?u‌​seSSL=false", "root", "1234");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a Exception?

Comment: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: Please update the question with that exception

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your MySQL driver is compatable to your MySQL vresion.

Comment: My connector/J is 5.1.43 and mySQL server is 5.7.19 and they are compatible I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to set useSSL to true in your connection parameters for MySQL

So replace "useSSL=false" to "useSSL=true" like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gym?u‌​seSSL=true
```